# Can Mad Dog Primer be used on the exterior of my cedar clapboard home with Ben Moore flat paint?

Tags: repainting, primer, preparation, cedar

My home is mudding all over (especially where the sun was hitting) and peeling in random spots. The mudding started right away and the peeling less than one month. We have cedar clapboards that the paint was in need of a new painting. House from 1986. The mad Dog primer was put on in 91 degree heat and the house was sprayed twice after.
The primer specs say that flat has to be tested because the acrylic content in it.
Has anyone seen this problem or have a good solution. The Mad Dog cannot be sanded.

Comment: What is "mudding all over"? Was the primer brushed, rolled or sprayed on? What does "flat has to be tested" mean - was there a lab test involved or just a test application or something else?

Comment: Mudding, not being a standard term for paint quality issues, seems like a poor word choice for a paint problem. Please [edit] in some pictures. But it sounds like you did it, and it didn't work, so the answer to the title question as proven by your experience is "No!"

Comment: If the primer has acrylic, you need acrylic paint for best results.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The mad dog primer was painted in with a brush. The flat Ben Moore paint was sprayed on - 2 coats. 
The specs for mad dog said to test the flat paint for 30 days - which did not happen. 
The elastic primer with the flat paint failed causing aligatoring. But would that cause peeling and cracking too?